# Improve FPS in Fallout 4

Tags: fallout-4, performance, framerate

My PC has integrated graphics, an AMD Radeon HD 7660D APU (3.4 GHz). I've done a clean install of the latest driver for it, but I still get atrocious FPS in Fallout 4. It stutters so much that it is almost unplayable when there are flames, many light sources, or weather effects.

I was wondering if, besides replacing my graphics card or installing mods, if there is any way to improve performance. This is what I have tried thus far:

- Setting preset graphics setting to "Low" (textures, shadows, everything to the lowest setting)
- Turning off all special effects (like lens flare, rain occlusion, etc)
- Turning off anti-aliasing (looks like trash!)

I wanted to turn off weather effects (rain effects performance the most) but I have not found a way to do so.

Does anyone have any suggestions for overall game performance for my setup?

**Other PC Specs:**

- 64-bit Windows 7 SP1
- 12GB RAM
- 1.49 TB of free HD space
- Direct X 11

Answer (score 4):

Data is from http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu_list.php.

[image]

As you can see, your GPU is not even half the rating of the minimum requirements (if compared to the GeForce).  You should not expect to be able to run the game.

Note:  I have no idea why the two minimum requirement cards have such a huge difference, but regardless, this is still way above the OP's hardware.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea my GPU was that bad. The machine is only like 4 years old! D: Is it possible to get a new graphics card if I have this integrated APU? I'm not sure how that works.

Comment: If it's a normal PC and it has free slots, the integrated graphics will not interfere with a separate GPU.  You can just buy a new graphics card, plug it in, and it'll go.

Comment: Considering the game is released November 2015, your PC isn't particularly new.

Comment: Yeah, it is a normal PC. Maybe I will have to do that, as I think the rest of my machine's stats are pretty good? It's probably not worth buying a whole new machine (especially since I want to keep Win 7)

Comment: Google for "fallout 4 system requirements" and do some research on whether your PC can run it.

Comment: @N-C "not worth buying a whole new machine" ? There's a direct correlation between Bethesda releasing a new game and me buying a 'new' computer. Look into acquiring a refurbished i7 (they're all quad cores; try to get one with HT) and, in the meantime, the most expensive video card you can afford as you'll probably then be able to get away with just transferring it to a 'new' machine. I have a HD7770, and when I went from a 3.0ghz dual core (basically what you have) to a 2.8ghz HT quad, it was like night and day. Currently, your bottleneck is your vid card; buy one, and it will become your CPU

Answer (score 3):

You can supposedly do this by [changing an INI file](https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/3381230-how-do-you-turn-off-rainweather-effects/) though this causes some people's [games](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/492378806386178623/) to [crash](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3tv9cr/need_help_on_how_to_disable_rain/).
Alternately, if you're not averse to it, whenever the rain starts up, press `~` to open the terminal and type `fw 15e` or `fw 2b52a` to force the weather system into [a 'clear day' state](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_console_commands).

Of course, if you do decide to use mods someday, there are plenty of nice ones that will accomplish this task. [Climate Control](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/4698), [No Rain](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/19300), [FogOut](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/2428), [AlwaysClearWeather](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/8405), and [ClearWeatherOnly](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/6339) have settings for permanently disabling weather, and mods like [ULG](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/73) include other options to increase your framerate.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 main ways to deal with Fallout 4 to try to get some more FPS from it:
* To configure your options for video card for max boost/performance with less quality with software from the manufacturer of the card
* to configure basic options in standard launcher
* to modify .ini files.
* replace textures - in Nexus Modes there are "Performance textures", "Ultra Low Resolution Textures etc.".I personally used "Texture Optimization Project" and can verify that the difference was or near to zero or very low so this pack is better to avoid for tests at first.

About .ini files - you can read by your own and look for recommendations.
But easy way to go instead of looking for every string and the meaning -  I would like to recommend to download and to use - "Fallout 4 Configuration Tool - By Bilago". This is the best Tweaker. There is no need to explain details because the tool has also the notes for all the main options. The main rule is to reduce visible things, shadows, lighting effects etc.
All the noted things are available from nexusmods website.
Sorry, you video card seems to be really weak and I suppose that with standard launcher you have around 15-20 FPS. You should tweak almost all possible.